# Not seeing dimensions of parent object?

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, units

I want to change the dimension of multiple object as whole. I moved them to parent object. But how to enable the dimensions of parent object.

My purpose is if I change dimension of parent object than all child object dimension should change.

[image]

Currently I am not seeing dimension of parent object. Is there any other way around?

Comment: An empty has no dimensions. Use a normal object.

Comment: What normal. Sorry I am new to blender. I want to change dimensions of whole object instead of multiple objects

Comment: I mean you can use a parent object like a cube, not an "empty" object. Make all others children and then change the dimensions of the parent. However, chances are you don't want to change the "dimensions" in the first place but simply scale them. Does selecting the objects and pressing "s" do what you want?

Comment: No scaling is not I want.   i want to scale in real world metrices.

Comment: Did my suggestion with the parent solve your problem? If not, please provide more info what you want and how it does not work.

Comment: @Dimali No, I have multiple objects and I want to change the size with actual unit metric dimension. You are right I can scale the object but I want to see the dimension of whole object and want make modifications to dimension to change the scale of object. It is necessary as sometime models are very big or very small. This way I have reference how object will look like.